# Levelplot for categorical data?

Tags: r, lattice

I want to produce a levelplot based on a matrix with the the following code.

```
library("lattice")
x<-c(0:10)
y=seq(0,0.9,by=0.1)
z <- expand.grid(cost_hs, rr_ls)
val<-sample(c("A","B","C"),110,replace = T)
z$value=as.factor(val)
levelplot(value ~ Var1*Var2,data=z,main="")
```

My question is about the legend. The "value" is defined as categorical data, how to fix the legend as discrete label.
[image]

Comment: It's not answering your question directly, but this would be trivial to do in ggplot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`levelplot` doesn't really seem to be designed for categorical tile plots like this. You *can* use some hacky tricks in the `colorkey` argument to get an approximation like this:

```r
levelplot(value ~ Var1 * Var2, data = z, main = "", regions = TRUE,
          colorkey = list(at = c(0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5),
                          labels = c('', 'A', '', 'B', '', 'C', ''),
                          col = c('#ff80ff', '#ff80ff', 'white', 
                                  'white', '#80ffff', '#80ffff')))
```

[image]

I think you would get a better result using `ggplot`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(z, aes(Var1, Var2, fill = value)) +
  geom_tile() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c(A = '#ff80ff', B = 'white', C = '#80ffff')) +
  theme_classic(base_size = 16) +
  coord_cartesian(expand = FALSE) +
  theme(panel.border = element_rect(fill = NA),
        axis.line = element_blank())
```

[image]